# Theme.Material.Light и Theme.Holo.Light

Tags: android, android-style

Народ, почему я не могу изменить цвета темы Theme.Holo.Light, но при этом теми же атрибутами меняется тема Theme.Material.Light?

Вот код:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    </style>
```

а в другой теме с теми же атрибутами уже не работает:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

"аndroid:" во втором примере мне подсказала убрать IDE, но все равно не работает, помогите!

Comment: У вас не те же атрибуты, а разные. Точнее - во втором случае нет пространства имён

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо 2го варианта написать так:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

Comment: то же самое, дело в том, что тема то работает, не все атрибуты работают мои, которые в <item></item>

Comment: например, не изменился цвет панели действий, хотя тут он меняться должен на мой.